# Taylor Polynomial Approximations

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am asked to find a Taylor Polynomial approximation accurate to within $10^{-3}$ for the following function

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}, x \in [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$$

We know the Taylor expansion for $f(x)$ is

$$\frac{1}{x+1} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - x^5 ...$$

Question 1:

Is the remainder for $f(x)$

$$|R_n(x)|\leq \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Question 2:

I choose $n=5$ for an adequate approximation that is within the desired approximation of $10^{-3}$.

So

$$\max_{x\in[\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]}|R_5(x)|\leq \frac{|x|^{6}}{7!}$$

Because

$$\frac{6}{7!} \leq 10^{-3}$$

Since I chose $n=5$ I would simply write out a 5th order Taylor polynomial for $f(x)$. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: We know that the derivative of $\frac{1}{x+1}$ is $\ln(x+1)$, so I am a little confused...And I think I need to put in $\pm\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304926/bounding-approximation-error-for-taylor-polynomial?rq=1

Comment: I beg your pardon, but the question provided through the link is not explicitly pertaining to the problem above (although I did vote it up).

Comment: I am just posting this if it might help, I didn't flag as duplicate, why are you upset?

Comment: The error is much bigger than that, no helpful factorial term. For positive $x$ one can use the estimate $x^{n+1}$. For negative $x$ it is worse.   Since you actually know the exact sum, you know the exact error. But maybe you are expected to use the Lagrange estimate.

Comment: Thanks. $\frac{1}{840} \leq \frac{1}{100}$, but I think I am working off of an incorrect R.

Comment: Just see this $|R_n |\leq a_{n+1}$

Comment: It some type of recurrence that I am missing here?

Comment: Did you check in depth the answer below before accepting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = \sum \frac{a_n x^n}{n!}$

And if the series is an alernating series the error is less than the next term in the series.

So yes, in general, error = $\dfrac {|a_{n+1} x^{n+1}|}{(n+1)!}$

However, for this series $a_{n+1} = (-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!$

error $< x^{n+1}$

One more note.  $|x| < \frac{1}{2}, x^{n+1} < 2^{-(n+1)}$

you need nine terms.  $x^{10} < \frac{1}{1024}$

Comment: "error $< x^{n+1}$" True for $x$ in $(0,1)$ but not for $x$ in $(-1/2,0)$.